# datetimepicker scrolls in the reverse direction for timepicker when using the mousewheel

Tags: jquery, datetimepicker

I am using the jquery datetimepicker plugin provided [here](https://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/datetimepicker/) and currently facing weird reversed-scroll issue.

I have downloaded the zip from their git [repo](https://github.com/xdan/datetimepicker), run `npm install` followed by `npm run build`and then opened `index.html` file but somehow the direction of scroll for timepicker is reversed for me and I can't somehow able to figure out why it works so.
|
In their demo site, it works properly. i.e. clicking on up arrow scrolls down and reveals the content above but for me it works in reverse direction.

[image]

So when I mousewheel up, it scrolls down.

Answer (score 1):

Try in line 809 of the file `jquery.datetimepicker.full.js`:

```
if ('deltaY' in e) {
  deltaY = -e.deltaY;
}
```

instead of:

```
if ('deltaY' in e) {
  deltaY = e.deltaY;
}
```

This solved the issue for me.

Source: https://github.com/xdan/datetimepicker/issues/763